# how do i have different chats in chatgpt API?

Tags: flutter, http, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am not sure if it is possible to have different chats in a API to chatgpt.

My goal are a few:

- user can have a conversation with chatgpt
- user can only access their own conversation
  My issue is:
- I cant differentiate between users at the moment and I cant find any help.

I tried looking through the docs and stackoverflow and using chatgpt but nothing worked.

How do i differentiate between the chats?

The code below works fine.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class OpenAI {
  static Future<String> chatGPT(String prompt) async {
    final String url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';

    String? gptKey = dotenv.env['GPT'];

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $gptKey',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        'messages': [
          {'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are a helpful assistant.'},
          {'role': 'user', 'content': prompt},
        ],
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final choices = jsonResponse['choices'] as List<dynamic>;
      final reply = choices.first['message']['content'] as String;
      // print('chatgpt response $reply');
      return reply;
    } else {
      return 'Failed to process the request. Status code: ${response.statusCode}';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can store individual chat history in local storage or in a database..